# How do I add a foreign key to an existing table in Informix?

Tags: informix

I would like to create a foreign key for a certain database table **table_a**, which refers to another table **table_b** for the column **column_id**. The name of the foreign key should be **my_foreign_key_column_id**.

I don't know how to create this foreign key in the Informix database?

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-alter-table-statement) statement does the job (you need the [multiple column constraint format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=clause-multiple-column-constraint-format) information):

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_a
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (column_id)
        REFERENCES table_b(column_id)
        CONSTRAINT my_foreign_key_column_id;
```